# QJSEngine crashes when used in multithreading program

Tags: javascript, c++, multithreading, qt, thread-safety

I have a program where an `QJSEngine` object is used with several different threads. There should be no concurrent access - a thread is created, calling or evaluating something, and then this thread is deleted.

However there are random crashes of program while using `QJSEngine`. All crashes are occured inside the private `QJSEngine` functions related to allocating or freeing memory. Example:

```
// QV4::PersistentValueStorage::allocate() (qv4persistent.cpp):

Value *PersistentValueStorage::allocate()
{
    Page *p = static_cast<Page *>(firstPage);
    while (p) {
        if (p->header.freeList != -1)
            break;
        p = p->header.next;
    }
    if (!p)
        p = allocatePage(this);

    Value *v = p->values + p->header.freeList;
    p->header.freeList = v->int_32();   // !!! Get SEGFAULT here

    // ....
}
```

I've found a [bugreport](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-83410) that is similar to my problem. The reporter provided the minimal code that reproduces the problem:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QJSEngine>
#include <QThread>
#include <QTimer>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);
    QJSEngine engine;
    engine.installExtensions(QJSEngine::ConsoleExtension);
    engine.evaluate("var iteration = 0;");

    auto function = engine.evaluate(R"((
        function()
        {
            if (++iteration % 100 == 0)
                console.log(iteration);
        }
    ))");

    QThread thread;
    thread.start();

    QTimer timer;
    QObject::connect(&timer, &QTimer::timeout, &engine, [&]{function.call();}, Qt::DirectConnection);
    timer.moveToThread(&thread); // Comment it if you want to test QJSEngine in the main thread
    QMetaObject::invokeMethod(&timer, "start", Q_ARG(int, 0));

    return app.exec();
}
```

Doing the same thing in the main thread (thread where `QJSEngine` was created) does not crash the program.

Could you please tell me how to make `QJSEngine` thread-safe for this situation? The reported provided template functions `safeEngineCall()` to wrap engine calls in blocking queue but I can't understand how to use it.

Thanks in advance.

**UPD:** I had an idea to wrap `QJSValue::call()` to a thread-safe function to force it call in the `QJSEngine`'s object thread by using `QMetaObject::invokeMethod()`:

**threadsafeqjsengine.h**

```
class ThreadSafeQJSEngine : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

    QJSEngine* m_engine;

public:
    ThreadSafeQJSEngine(QObject *parent = Q_NULLPTR);
    virtual ~ThreadSafeQJSEngine();

    // ...

    QJSValue call(QJSValue value, const QJSValueList& args);

    // ...

private slots:
    inline QJSValue call_imp(QJSValue value, const QJSValueList& args) {
        return value.engine() == m_engine ? value.call(args) : QJSValue();
    }
    // ...
};
```

**threadsafeqjsengine.cpp**

```
ThreadSafeQJSEngine::ThreadSafeQJSEngine(QObject *parent)
    : QObject(parent)
{
    m_engine = new QJSEngine;
}

ThreadSafeQJSEngine::~ThreadSafeQJSEngine()
{
    delete m_engine;
}

QJSValue ThreadSafeQJSEngine::call(QJSValue value, const QJSValueList &args)
{
    if (QThread::currentThread() != this->thread())
    {
        QJSValue result;
        QMetaObject::invokeMethod(this,
                                  "call_imp",
                                  Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection,
                                  Q_RETURN_ARG(QJSValue, result),
                                  Q_ARG(QJSValue, value),
                                  Q_ARG(const QJSValueList&, args)
                                  );

        return result;

    }
    else
    {
        return call_imp(value, args);
    }
}

// ...
```

**main.cpp**

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);
    ThreadSafeQJSEngine engine;

    // The same as before 
    // ...

    QObject::connect(&timer, &QTimer::timeout, &engine, [&]{engine.call(function);}, Qt::DirectConnection);
    
    // The same as before 
    // ...  
}
```

But the problem is not gone and it crashes as usual. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I did some testing and the behavior seems to vary by Qt version. For instance with Qt 5.12.12 Win10 MSVC I couldn't even get your original example to crash, but it did readily on 5.14.2.

The example is a bit contrived really... if you want to make re-usable JS code then I'd perhaps import that as a module into the JSE global object and call a function from the module.  Modules are cached so after the first use it's almost "free" to import it again (to get a reference) and call a function from the module. Then there's no reason to even hold a reference to the JSValue function in the first place.

Anyway, don't ask me why exactly but adding a `JSEngine::collectGarbage()` after the `function.call()` seems to fix your example. *Or* slowing the timer interval down to 1ms. I *suspect* that there is some race condition with the `JSValue` function object and letting the engine "collect itself" after the `function.call()` is the ultimate fix here (not the GC per sé).

I also tried adding a mutex (among other things) but that doesn't seem to help (though it's probably a good idea if you're going to be calling the engine from multiple threads).  I also expanded the example to limit the number of loops and (attempt to) exit cleanly afterwards.

```cpp
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QJSEngine>
#include <QMutex>
#include <QThread>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);
    QJSEngine engine;
    engine.installExtensions(QJSEngine::ConsoleExtension);

    engine.evaluate("var iteration = 0;");
    static QJSValue function = engine.evaluate(
        "(function() { if ((++iteration) % 100 == 0) console.log(iteration); })"
    );
    if (function.isError()) {
        qDebug() << function.toString();
        return -1;
    }

    const int interval = 0;  // how often; Try >= 1ms and comment the collectGarbage() call
    const int maxIterations = 20000;  // how many times
    int iteration = 0;  // run counter

    QMutex mutex;
    QTimer timer;
    QObject::connect(&timer, &QTimer::timeout, &engine, [&]
    {
        // QMutexLocker locker(&mutex);  // optional?
        if (!teration) {
             qDebug() << "Calling function from thread" << QThread::currentThread()
                      << "; App thread is" << qApp->thread();
        }
        if (function.isCallable()) {
          function.call();
          engine.collectGarbage();  // < seems to fix things
        }
        else {
          qDebug() << "function is not callable!";
          qApp->exit(1);
        }
        if (iteration == maxIterations) {
          qApp->exit(0);
        }
    }, Qt::DirectConnection);

    if (true)  // false to test QJSEngine in the main thread.
    {
      QThread *thread = new QThread;
      // ensure graceful shutdown
      QObject::connect(qApp, &QCoreApplication::aboutToQuit, qApp, [&]() {
        thread->quit();
        thread->wait();
        thread->deleteLater();
      });
      QObject::connect(thread, &QThread::finished, &timer, &QTimer::stop);
      // move timer and start thread
      timer.moveToThread(thread);
      thread->start();
    }
    else {
      QObject::connect(qApp, &QCoreApplication::aboutToQuit, &timer, &QTimer::stop);
    }

    QMetaObject::invokeMethod(&timer, "start", Q_ARG(int, interval));
    return app.exec();
}
```

HTH,

-Max

Answer (score 0):

I have found the workaround and it is based on the bugreport creator's solution. I [adapted it](https://github.com/nst1911/thread-safe-qjsengine) for my purposes and provide an example.

If `QJSEngine` and `QJSValue` methods are called inside a lambda via `QMetaObject::invokeMethod` with blocking queue, it works good and there are no crashes.

But on the other hand, if JS script evaluating takes a lot of time, it blocks all other threads including GUI.